# Getting list of opened ssh connections by name

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a config file in my .ssh dir that looks like this

```
Host somehostA
HostName 123.45.67.89
User katsh
```

So from my local machine, i can ssh into multiple machines by their name in the config file, like so

```
ssh somehostA
ssh somehostB
ssh somehostC
...
etc
```

Is it possible to get a list of all machines i am connected to, by their name?

I know I can do:

```
 lsof -i tcp -n | grep '\<ssh\>'
```

and i'll get something like

```
ssh        9871 katsh    3u  IPv4 400199      0t0  TCP 987.654.2.2:47329->987.654.2.2:47329:ssh (ESTABLISHED)
ssh       20554 katsh    3u  IPv4 443965      0t0  TCP 123.456.7.8:41923->123.456.7.8:ssh (ESTABLISHED)
```

But it does not list their names, just IP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want a list of names you can do something like this

```
sudo netstat -atp | grep 'ESTABLISHED.*ssh ' | awk '{print $5}'| sed 's/:ssh//'
```

- get the list of used ports
- filter out those that are ssh related. You need a space after ssh to remove the inbound connections to the local sshd.
- get the name from the list
- remove the :ssh

Some example output, without the filter for sshd

```
host1.lan
192.168.1.71:51053
192.168.1.71:50323
host2.lan
192.168.1.71:50929
```

which shows the outgoing connections to host1 and host2 but also shows the inbound connections for the putty sessions I have to the demonstration host.

Some example output with the local sshd connections filtered out

```
host1.lan
host2.lan
```

Comment: `awk` can do a `grep`: `sudo netstat -atp | awk '/ESTABLISHED.*ssh/ { print $5 }'...`.

Comment: @quanta: ooh yes, I keep forgetting about that - thanks.

Comment: In fedora 26 netstat, I use the `-W` flag to provide wide output so my hostnames are not truncated at all.

Answer (score 5):

The `w` command seems to do it - I've connected from my test VM, from my desktop (BLACKBEAUTY) then sshed from the VM into my VPS (example.com - not my real domain) and the output is as follows

```
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
geek     pts/2    blackbeauty      21:31    1:46   0.63s  0.02s ssh example.com
geek     pts/3    blackbeauty      21:32    0.00s  0.57s  0.00s w
```

Tie that in with `grep ssh` and you should be able to extract lines where WHAT is ssh for more clarity.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sudo netstat -atp | grep 'ESTABLISHED.*ssh'
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Could you please leave a comment?

Comment: Yeah that was unfair. i upvoted. every answer appreciated.